# In Workflow Manager 1.0, how can I access value of Workflow 'Out' argument from the client?

Tags: workflow-foundation-4, workflow-manager-1.x

This article describes how to read Out arguments of a Workflow, but when using Workflow Manager 1.0, you don't have access to the workflow running in a host:

- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rjacobs/archive/2009/09/24/wf4-how-to-access-out-arguments.aspx

I have read the following documents about Workflow Manager 1.0

- [Developers Introduction to Windows Workflow 1.0](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee342461.aspx)
- [Workflow Manager 1.0 Tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj193528(v=azure.10).aspx)
- [How to create a Workflow for Workflow Manager 1.0](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn217861(v=azure.10).aspx)
- [What is Workflow Manager 1.0](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj193471(v=azure.10).aspx)
- [Installing and configuring Workflow Manager 1.0](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj193478(v=azure.10).aspx)

I have downloaded and dissected he sample code provided by microsoft, but the information I need is not included.

- [Workflow Manager 1.0 Samples](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Workflow-Manager-10-Samples-0afa14dd)

All the samples appear to return values using

> WorkflowInstance.UserStatus

and set this using a SetUserStatus activity in the workflow, which isn't much use if you want to read the value of an Out argument defined in the workflow itself.

Comment: @Will is this better?

Comment: Much!  Have you tried any code?  If so, add that as well.